# awk find patterns (stored in a file) in a file

Tags: unix, awk

I am learning awk and I am having a hard time trying to do this :

I have a file, let's name it `pattern_file.txt`, which contains multiple patterns, one per line. For example, it looks like this :

pattern_file.txt

```
PATTERN1
PATTERN2
PATTERN3
PATTERN4
```

I have a second file, containing some text. Let's name it `text_file.txt`. It looks like this:

text_file.txt

```
xxxxxxxxPATTERN1xxxxxxx
yyyyyPATTERN2yyyy
zzzzzzzzzPATTERN3zzzzzz
```

What I am trying to do is : If one of the patterns in the `pattern_file.txt` is present in the current line read in `text_file.txt`, print the line.

I know how to print a line with awk, what gives me a hard time is to use the pattern stored in the `pattern_file.txt` and verify if one of them is present.

Comment: did you try `grep -f patternfile yourfile` ?

Comment: Yes this works all fine with grep but I would like to use awk because I have multiple things to do after the line is found

Comment: Never use the word "pattern" as it's ambiguous - always use "string" or "regexp", whichever one you mean. The 2 answers you have so far will behave very differently when the contents of "pattern_file.txt" contain regexp metacharacters like `.` or `*` because they each make different assumptions about what you mean by "pattern".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In awk using `index`

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1];next}{for(i in a)if(index($0,i)) print}' pattern text
xxxxxxxxPATTERN1xxxxxxx
yyyyyPATTERN2yyyy
zzzzzzzzzPATTERN3zzzzzz
```

Store "patterns" to a hash and for each record use `index` to try to find the "patterns" from the record.

Comment: thank you, worked perfectly. I forgot to ask if there is a way to ignore case ?

Comment: For case you need to use for example `tolower`: `...index(tolower($0),tolower(i))`.

Comment: Actually, it's probably more efficient to make the "patterns" lower case while hashing: `NR==FNR{a[tolower($1)];next}{for(i in a)if(index($0,tolower(i))) print}`. (Untested).

Comment: the second `tolower` should be on $0 and not on i, but I understood the way to go. It works like a charm thank you !

Comment: You are right. Leaving it unfixed for selfshaming. :D

Answer (score 2):

A *variation* of this helpful [James Brown's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43042366/5291015) using `match()` which *also* does *regex* match (and) returns the starting index of the matching string,

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$0]; next}{for (i in a) if (match($0,i)) print}' pattern_file.txt text_file.txt
```

which returns me the lines needed.

On printing the return values from the `match()` function

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$0]; next}{for (i in a) if (match($0,i)) print RSTART}' pattern_file.txt text_file.txt
```

gives an output as

```
9   # Meaning 'PATTERN1' match started at index 9 in 'xxxxxxxxPATTERN1xxxxxxx' 
6
10
```